# Import Bitcoin Wallet using Private Key

Tags: react-native, blockchain, bitcoin

How can I import a Testnet bitcoin wallet using private key just for testing in a react native expo project.

I have tried bitcoin js but it isn't supported in expo managed project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib in React Native (Expo) but you first have to use Browserify.

```
$ npm install bitcoinjs-lib browserify
$ npx browserify --standalone bitcoin - -o bitcoinjs-lib.js <<<"module.exports = require('bitcoinjs-lib');"
```

More info here, good luck.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitcoinjs-lib